# How to kill the nameserver process in java

Tags: java, client-server, corba, idl, nameservers

I built a client server application using an IDL file for client server communication across the network. Both the client and server programs are in java. When the user enters exit, both the server and the client exit. However I'm unable to kill the nameserver process.
I started the nameserver using the command

tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1050

How can I kill the nameserver in the client or server programs( which are in java)?

Comment: you cannot stop the standard nameserver with java-based methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the tnameserv you'll have to kill it via the kill command (linux,unix) or Ctrl+C (windows)

If on linux/unix, this should do the trick:

```
killall tnameserv
```

see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/tnameserv.html#stoppingnameserver

Edit:

If you want to issue the killall command from withing java use:

```
runtime.exec("killall tnameserv");
```

see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Thoughts:

It seems odd to have started the tnameserv from outside of our program, and then try to kill it from within.  (permission issues, other users using the nameserv, etc, etc.)  Depending on your needs, why not start the tnameserv from within you app?

Comment: from the linux command line.  same place you run the 'tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1050' command from.

Comment: but the question was how to kill IN the client or server app (java)!

Comment: you *could* use runtime.exec() from inside java to run the killall command.  However, now your program only works on systems that have killall (which might be ok).  I'll edit my answer.